# What Nutch is all about?

Tags: search-engine, nutch

Im going to make my own search engine.

When searching about search engine, crawler, and so on, I confused about [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/).

I don’t understand what is Nutch. Is it for internal use like Lucene (correct me if Im wrong) or a framework for creating a search engine (example:google, bing, yahoo)?

Answer (score 2):

Nutch is a full featured search engine - it can crawl external web sites, and it understands and respects robots.txt.

http://nutch.apache.org/about.html

> Overview Nutch is open source
>   web-search software. It builds on
>   Lucene and Solr, adding web-specifics,
>   such as a crawler, a link-graph
>   database, parsers for HTML and other
>   document formats, etc.
>
> Nutch can run on a single machine, but
>   gains a lot of its strength from
>   running in a Hadoop cluster
>
> The system can be enhanced (eg other
>   document formats can be parsed) using
>   a plugin mechanism.
>
> For more information about Nutch,
>   please see the Nutch wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Nutch is a ready-made, configurable web crawler with a Java Servlet for performing searches.  If you wanted to do this as a project, Nutch probably does too much since all that's left is creating the pages for entering searches and displaying results.